# I have tried everything the bookmarks in edge are permanently gone

Tags: microsoft-edge

I've formatted my pc then all of a sudden my Microsoft edge bookmarks are gone permanently, yet people say they aren't really gone for good are they or not?

Comment: Yes; Your bookmarks are gone.  Edge does not have any feature to synchronize your bookmarks into the cloud built-in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been signed into a Microsoft account before formatting, and did Sync
your data
(see [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/sync-edge-bookmarks-between-windows-10-devices/)),
then all you have to do is turn Sync on again in Edge.

If you have done none of this, and have never exported or otherwise saved the
bookmarks, then I'm afraid that they are lost.

Note that if you have taken a backup of your disk before formatting,
then your favorites may still be returned if your copy back this file:

> `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\
>   MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\DataStore\Data\nouser1\120712-0049\DBStore\Spartan.edb`

For good measures, you might copy back the entire folder.
But take a backup of it before starting.